# Javascript: character in array

Tags: javascript, arrays, character

If I enter "12314" in the 'word' string below, everything works as intended. If I enter characters such as "abacd", the code fails.  Can anyone tell me why? (1 in [1,2,3,1,4]) works, but ('a' in [a,b,a,c,d] fails. I'm fairly new to Javascript.

```
var word = "abacd";

function duplicateEncode(word){

  var repeat = [];
  var result = [];
  var letters = word.split('');

  for (i=0; i < letters.length; i++){
    if (letters[i] in repeat) {
        result.push(")");
    } else {
        result.push("(");
    }
    repeat.push(letters[i]);
  }
  return result;
}
```

Comment: "it fails"... what error do you get?

Comment: Can you please specify the desired output

Comment: I'm looking for "(" the first time a character is encountered in the string and ")" if it's already been found. "abacd" should return "(()((" and "12314" should return "((()(".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in operator:

> A string or symbol representing a property name or array index (non-symbols will be coerced to strings).

In your case it's working because its looking at the index not the value of the string.   When using the 'in' operator on an array its using the index as the properties

---

Play around with this:

```
> 1 in [1,2] //-> true
> 1 in [1]   //-> false (only one item in the list
> 1 in [2,2] // -> true


> Object.keys([2,3,4])  // -> ['0', '1', '2' ]
//in your case you would want to use indexOf
>['a','b','c'],indexOf('a') -> 0
>['a','b','c'],indexOf('e') -> -1
```

---

To fix your issue replace `in` with:

```
for (i=0; i < letters.length; i++){
 if (repeat.indexOf(letter[i]) > -1) {
    result.push(")");
 } else {
    result.push("(");
 }
 repeat.push(letters[i]);
}
```

Comment: Thank you Nix, that helps.  Can you tell me how I would search the letter array for a specific character?

Comment: You would want to use index of.  `['a','b','c'],indexOf('a')` would return the index if it finds it, if not it will return `-1`

Comment: @Nix you can move code of pushing in `repeat` in else block. This will ensure only unique values in repeat. [Sample Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/RajeshDixit/nf2jr8g8/)

Answer (score 0):

try following code...

```
function duplicateEncode(word){

  var repeat = [];
  var result = [];
  var letters = word.split('');
  for (i=0; i < letters.length; i++){
      if (repeat.indexOf(letters[i]) != -1) {
          result.push(")");
      } else {
          result.push("(");
      }
      repeat.push(letters[i]);
   }
   return result;
 }
```

Comment: Thank you, that fixes the problem.

Comment: @JamesBeau Pleases mark it as correct option... thank you :)